# SPARQL queries with blank-nodes as subjects

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata, blank-nodes

I have data like this:

```
<http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q1000019>  <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank>
                                 [<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#rankValue> "0.15"^^xsd:float] .
<http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q100004>   <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank>
                                 [<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#rankValue> "0.15"^^xsd:float] .
<http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q1000047>  <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank>
                                 [<http://purl.org/voc/vrank#rankValue> "0.15"^^xsd:float] .
```

And I am trying a query like this:

```
SELECT ?c WHERE {?s <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank> ?c}
```

This just returns a blank node. How do get the value 0.15 which is between quotes here?

Comment: It returns a blank node because the value of the property `hasRank` is a blank node. You have to resolve the blank node, i.e. in your case get the value of `rankValue`. This can be seen as a chain, i.e. `?s :hasRank ?rank . ?rank :rankValue ?value`

Comment: Using property paths: `?s vrank:hasRank/vrank:rankValue ?v`. Source: http://people.aifb.kit.edu/ath/

Answer (score 1):

You can just lift the pattern you can see in the data (reformatted a little):

```
SELECT ?c 
WHERE 
{ 
    ?s <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank> [ 
        <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#rankValue> ?c 
    ]
}
```

To explain, `[ ... content ... ]` is a convenience in turtle and sparql to introduce a bnode (typically in an object position) and add some properties of that bnode.

Answer (score 1):

```
DESCRIBE ?c
where {?s <http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q1000047> <http://purl.org/voc/vrank#hasRank> ?c}
```

This will give you all info about your BN `(?c)`